# Need to find parents of UDF elements in XSL

Tags: xslt

the xml has this format:

```
UDF Fields

Inline Portion - Child of multiple Nodes

<Activity>

    <UDF>
        <TypeObjectId>458</TypeObjectId>
        <TextValue>MILS-Z.M1.01</TextValue>
    </UDF>


Definition Portion - Child of top node

    <UDFType>
        <DataType>0</DataType>
        <IsSecureCode>0</IsSecureCode>
        <ObjectId>458</ObjectId>
        <SubjectArea>0</SubjectArea>
        <Title>Contract Package</Title>
    </UDFType>
```

I need to find the parents of the UDF by going in through UDFType, looping a search for UDF and then listing the parents of the UDF. Any advice?

Comment: Please add more clarity -  what is the connection between udf and udf type? What does `Child of multiple nodes` mean? And expected results?

Comment: Do not try to describe the structure of your XML. If your XML is huge, try to post a simplified form of it.

Comment: The structure is like this <BusinessObjects>
   <UDFType>
       <Project>
          <WBS>
             <UDF>

Comment: You are still far from giving us a comprehensible structure of your XML. Moreover, do not use comment, just edit your question.

Comment: Please think of how a [question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) should look here.

Comment: I came back to see if you added more detail but here I see you made it more confusing.. You said UDF is child of multiple nodes and show that it appears under activity. However your 'structure' has no mention of activity tag? Are you deliberately making it hard to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath: `//UDF/..` to match the parent nodes of all `UDF` elements. Or you could just do `//*[UDF]`, which specifically matches any element that has a `UDF` child.